# How to modify the fill color of an SVG image when being served as background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

Placing the SVG output directly inline with the page code I am able to simply modify fill colors with CSS like so:

```css
polygon.mystar {
    fill: blue;
}​

circle.mycircle {
    fill: green;
}
```

This works great, however I'm looking for a way to modify the "fill" attribute of an SVG when it's being served as a BACKGROUND-IMAGE.

```css
html {      
    background-image: url(../img/bg.svg);
}
```

How can I change the colors now?  Is it even possible?

For reference, here are the contents of my external SVG file:

```svg
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="320px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 320 100" enable-background="new 0 0 320 100" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon class="mystar" fill="#3CB54A" points="134.973,14.204 143.295,31.066 161.903,33.77 148.438,46.896 151.617,65.43 134.973,56.679 
    118.329,65.43 121.507,46.896 108.042,33.77 126.65,31.066 "/>
<circle class="mycircle" fill="#ED1F24" cx="202.028" cy="58.342" r="12.26"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

I needed something similar and wanted to stick with CSS. Here are LESS and SCSS mixins as well as plain CSS that can help you with this. Unfortunately, it's browser support is a bit lax. See below for details on browser support.

LESS mixin:

```less
.element-color(@color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...><g stroke="@{color}" ... /></g></svg>');
}
```

LESS usage:

```less
.element-color(#fff);
```

---

SCSS mixin:

```scss
@mixin element-color($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...><g stroke="#{$color}" ... /></g></svg>');
}
```

SCSS usage:

```scss
@include element-color(#fff);
```

---

CSS:

```css
// color: red
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...><g stroke="red" ... /></g></svg>');
```

---

[Here is more info](http://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) on embedding the full SVG code into your CSS file. It also mentioned browser compatibility which is a bit too small for this to be a viable option.

Comment: Although there is a little overhead, because I have to hardcoded all svg items, I think this is the best solution for a while. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a CSS preprocessor like Sass or Less if you want to use in this way. If you aren't using one you'll just need to use that background-image line for each colour

Comment: Note that you must urlencode the `#` character for your hex colors to make this work in Firefox. So something like `<svg fill="#ffffff" ...></svg>` becomes `<svg fill="%23ffffff" ...></svg>`.

Comment: Sweet method. Do you have to hard encode the svg into the background-image like that? Can you not just link out to it somehow?

Comment: @luke I didn't explore that option. I assume with a gulp task you could import from another file but I am not sure if you could do that dynamically. You should try it though! Could be sweet.

Comment: A bit late to the party but how would you do that with SASS?

Comment: @kstratis SASS and SCSS files can import each other, so the SCSS example should be valid for SASS, too.

Comment: Problem with this method is that you miss out on browser cache.

Comment: Problem with this method is it's all pre-processor based.

Comment: I found this site useful for giving you the perfectly encoded URL ready for use: https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ - Just copy the SVG code into it and copy out the returned CSS :-)

Comment: @Swen How can one do this?

Comment: I went this way, only to realise its blocked in production by any reverse proxy with decent security hearders, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213224/5506400. This was is vunerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Hello from 2022 and the `%23` thing is still relevant on Chromium, I just solved my issue this way.

Answer (score 313):

You can use CSS masks, With the 'mask' property, you create a mask that is applied to an element.

```
.icon {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(icon.svg);
    mask-image: url(icon.svg);
}
```

For more see this great article: https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images

Comment: this is good but when applied to an icon within an input field all the input text is hidden.

Comment: Super cool answer, but you can no longer use background-color in a hover or something like that

Comment: This seems to be barely supported if at all - too many users wouldn't be able to see this for it to be viable today in late 2018. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: Summer 2019: 94% of browsers on this planet support "mask-image" OR "-webkit-mask-image" styles

Comment: An addition for this in my case was useful is adding no-repeat:

mask-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: This answer is getting a lot more attention lately so I thought I should point out it is NOT a background image. This masks off the whole element including it's contents. If I wanted to dedicate an element to the image, I could just use a normal SVG with a fill set. Masking is useful for some cases but I dont think it really qualifies as an answer to this particular question.

Comment: It is 2021 and Chromium browsers still needs the "-webkit-mask-image" rule instead of "mask-image", aside from that, it works fine :3

Comment: @cronoklee - While you're techincally correct, `mask-image` effectively *can* be used to create a "background image". To use this approach on Element A when masking is not desired, create an Element B (using any method you prefer) that has the same position and dimensions as Element A and apply the `mask-image` to Element B.

Comment: @rinogo : Or a ::before pseudo-element if you can't change the HTML markup :)

Comment: This seems to cause strange artifacts around the edges of an image when it is rotated via `transform: rotate(...)`. Any solution?

Comment: The best answer in my opinion. Doesn't require different source images and filters, which didn't work great in my case. Also, it's supported by most browsers nowadays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

Comment: In case you've used backgroundSize and backgroundPositonX or Y, there are perfect matches in the mask world. just replace the background with a mask and add an optional Webkit prefix if you need it. all things work like a charm in 97-98% (late 2022)

Comment: `mask-size: cover;` was needed to make the size better in my case.

Comment: Learnt some new rules along this this trick --> mask-repeat: no-repeat; mask-size: contain; mask-position: center;  And for better browser support add all of these same rules with -webkit...

Answer (score 97):

One way to do this is to serve your svg from some server side mechanism.
Simply create a resource server side that outputs your svg according to GET parameters, and you serve it on a certain url.

Then you just use that url in your css.

Because as a background img, it isn't part of the DOM and you can't manipulate it.
Another possibility would be to use it regularly, embed it in a page in a normal way, but position it absolutely, make it full width & height of a page and then use z-index css property to put it behind all the other DOM elements on a page.

Comment: Don't forget if you're serving the SVG from a server-side script, to make sure you also send the correct [MIME header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_headers). In PHP this would be: `<?php header('Content-type: image/svg+xml'); ?>`

Comment: You can use the svg image as mask and manipulate the background-color of the element. This will have the same effect as changing the fill. (detailed answer provided)

Comment: This answer was great as of 2012, but now CSS masks and/or filters have been supported in all browsers for some time. I recommend that anyone reading this now check out the links in widged's answer below or just skip to [CSS Masks here](https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images#css-masks-1), which is a really easy solution -- note it still [requires 2 version of the rule, one with -webkit- prefix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) at the present time. For Microsoft Edge, currently CSS filters are supported but not yet masks.

Comment: There are many solutions provide bellow that work nowadays, I agree this answer no longer reflects the current state of possibilities.

Comment: Another issue with this solution is that for each color you need, you will make one more HTTP request, instead of fetching once and styling with `filter` or `mask-image`.

Answer (score 77):

Yet another approach is to use mask. You then change the background color of the masked element. This has the same effect as changing the fill attribute of the svg.

HTML:

```
<glyph class="star"/>
<glyph class="heart" />
<glyph class="heart" style="background-color: green"/>
<glyph class="heart" style="background-color: blue"/>
```

CSS:

```
glyph {
    display: inline-block;
    width:  24px;
    height: 24px;
}

glyph.star {
  -webkit-mask: url(star.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  mask: url(star.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
  background-color: yellow;
}

glyph.heart {
  -webkit-mask: url(heart.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  mask: url(heart.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
  background-color: red;
}
```

You will find a full tutorial here: http://codepen.io/noahblon/blog/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images (not my own). It proposes a variety of approaches (not limited to mask).

Comment: One thing to note on this is browser support.  I believe IE (as usual) is way behind on this.

Comment: Unfortunately `mask` is neither supported by IE nor Edge: http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Comment: Not working for me in Chrome either. Edit: Oh nvm... I don't have autoprefixer enabled. I thought vendors were supposed to stop using prefixes?!

Comment: Works in latest chrome and firefox

Comment: @alpipego Update! [Edge added support](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image) for `mask-image` in late 2017.

Answer (score 61):

Use the sepia filter along with hue-rotate, brightness, and saturation to create any color we want.

```
.colorize-pink {
  filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(-70deg) saturate(5);
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-colorizing-svg-backgrounds/

Comment: Use this CSS filter generator: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: Yes this should be the answer. Follow the css filter generator instructions from @djibe above.

Comment: This does not answer the question. what if he wants to fill different paths with different color?

Comment: This was incredibly helpful to me, along with @djibe 's comment

Comment: This is brilliant! I knew the filter sepia/hue-rotate trick but didn't think to look for a generator! \o/

Comment: The filtergenerator this is superawesome!

Answer (score 26):

It's possible with Sass! 
The only thing you have to do is to url-encode your svg code. And this is possible with a helper function in Sass. I've made a codepen for this. Look at this:

http://codepen.io/philippkuehn/pen/zGEjxB

```
// choose a color

$icon-color: #F84830;


// functions to urlencode the svg string

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }
  @return $string;
}

@function url-encode($string) {
  $map: (
    "%": "%25",
    "<": "%3C",
    ">": "%3E",
    " ": "%20",
    "!": "%21",
    "*": "%2A",
    "'": "%27",
    '"': "%22",
    "(": "%28",
    ")": "%29",
    ";": "%3B",
    ":": "%3A",
    "@": "%40",
    "&": "%26",
    "=": "%3D",
    "+": "%2B",
    "$": "%24",
    ",": "%2C",
    "/": "%2F",
    "?": "%3F",
    "#": "%23",
    "[": "%5B",
    "]": "%5D"
  );
  $new: $string;
  @each $search, $replace in $map {
    $new: str-replace($new, $search, $replace);
  }
  @return $new;
}

@function inline-svg($string) {
  @return url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,#{url-encode($string)}');
}


// icon styles
// note the fill="' + $icon-color + '"

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: inline-svg('<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="' + $icon-color + '" d="M18.7,10.1c-0.6,0.7-1,1.6-0.9,2.6c0,0.7-0.6,0.8-0.9,0.3c-1.1-2.1-0.4-5.1,0.7-7.2c0.2-0.4,0-0.8-0.5-0.7
  c-5.8,0.8-9,6.4-6.4,12c0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.5,0.5c-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.7-1.6-1.3c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.2-0.4-0.7-0.3-0.8,0.3
  c-0.5,2.5,0.3,5.3,2.1,7.1c4.4,4.5,13.9,1.7,13.4-5.1c-0.2-2.9-3.2-4.2-3.3-7.1C19.6,10,19.1,9.6,18.7,10.1z"/>
</svg>');
}
```

Comment: This works very good. Only problem: In IE10 the icon is way too small (i think 10% of given size.

Answer (score 13):

```
 .icon { 
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%; 
  background-size: cover;
}

.icon-orange { 
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(40deg) saturate(0.5) brightness(390%) saturate(4); 
  filter: hue-rotate(40deg) saturate(0.5) brightness(390%) saturate(4); 
}

.icon-yellow {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(70deg) saturate(100);
  filter: hue-rotate(70deg) saturate(100);
}
```

[codeben article and demo](http://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images)

Comment: This method will apply filter to a whole object, including children.

Answer (score 13):

If you are trying to use and SVG directly on CSS with `url()` like this;

```
a:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 451 451"><path d="M345.441,2...
```

You should encode the `#` to `%23`, otherwise it won't work.

```
<svg fill="%23FFF" ...
```

Answer (score 11):

Now you can achieve this on the client side like this:

```
var green = '3CB54A';
var red = 'ED1F24';
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  width="320px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 320 100" enable-background="new 0 0 320 100" xml:space="preserve"> <polygon class="mystar" fill="#'+green+'" points="134.973,14.204 143.295,31.066 161.903,33.77 148.438,46.896 151.617,65.43 134.973,56.679 118.329,65.43 121.507,46.896 108.042,33.77 126.65,31.066 "/><circle class="mycircle" fill="#'+red+'" cx="202.028" cy="58.342" r="12.26"/></svg>';      
var encoded = window.btoa(svg);
document.body.style.background = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encoded+")";
```

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/k0cx2b04/2/)

Comment: You should avoid the use of Base64 for SVG as it is unnecessary, makes your files bigger and even prevents GZIP from effectively compressing those chunks of code.

Comment: This encoding is happening on the client side, probably just for thorough escaping...

Comment: It goes without saying you can do anything with JS. The point is to avoid JS.

Answer (score 9):

Download your svg as text.

Modify your svg text using javascript to change the paint/stroke/fill color[s].

Then embed the modified svg string inline into your css as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10768631/62255).

Answer (score 9):

Since this comes up on Google despite the age, I thought I might as well give a solution that I'm employing in the distant future of 2022 after looking at the options here.

This is really just the mask solution from before, but on a pseudo-element.

```css
.icon {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
}
.icon::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center;
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-image: url("path/to/svg/icon.svg");
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position: center;
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("path/to/svg/icon.svg");
}
```

This works in all major browsers today, although obviously you can't have an SVG with multiple colors using this. That's the cost of business if the site doesn't let you inject them inline, or if you don't fancy doing font icons, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can store the SVG in a variable. Then manipulate the SVG string depending on your needs (i.e., set width, height, color, etc). Then use the result to set the background, e.g.

```scss
$circle-icon-svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" /></svg>';

$icon-color: #f00;
$icon-color-hover: #00f;

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
    $index: str-index($string, $search);

    @if $index {
        @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
    }

    @return $string;
}

@function svg-fill ($svg, $color) {
  @return str-replace($svg, '<svg', '<svg fill="#{$color}"');
}

@function svg-size ($svg, $width, $height) {
  $svg: str-replace($svg, '<svg', '<svg width="#{$width}"');
  $svg: str-replace($svg, '<svg', '<svg height="#{$height}"');

  @return $svg;
}

.icon {
  $icon-svg: svg-size($circle-icon-svg, 20, 20);

  width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,#{svg-fill($icon-svg, $icon-color)}');

  &:hover {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,#{svg-fill($icon-svg, $icon-color-hover)}');
  }
}
```

I have made a demo too, http://sassmeister.com/gist/4cf0265c5d0143a9e734.

This code makes a few assumptions about the SVG, e.g. that `<svg />` element does not have an existing fill colour and that neither width or height properties are set. Since the input is hardcoded in the SCSS document, it is quite easy to enforce these constraints.

Do not worry about the code duplication. [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip) compression makes the difference negligible.

Comment: Duplicate code is a code smell so suggesting people should not worry about duplicate code in the case of your example is not a good idea, however that said I can't see where your code is duplicated? I think it would read better if you just removed the comment altogether.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the brightness filter, any value greater than 1 makes the element brighter, and any value less than 1 makes it darker. So, we can make those light SVG’s dark, and vice versa, for example, this will make the svg darker:

```
filter: brightness(0);
```

In order to change the color and not only brightness level we can use sepia filter along with hue-rotate, brightness, for example:

```
.colorize-blue {
  filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(140deg) saturate(6);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you wanna swap in a simple way from white to black or some like that, try this:

```
filter: invert(100%);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own SCSS function for this. Adding the following to your config.rb file.

```
require 'sass'
require 'cgi'

module Sass::Script::Functions

  def inline_svg_image(path, fill)
    real_path = File.join(Compass.configuration.images_path, path.value)
    svg = data(real_path)
    svg.gsub! '{color}', fill.value
    encoded_svg = CGI::escape(svg).gsub('+', '%20')
    data_url = "url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encoded_svg + "')"
    Sass::Script::String.new(data_url)
  end

private

  def data(real_path)
    if File.readable?(real_path)
      File.open(real_path, "rb") {|io| io.read}
    else
      raise Compass::Error, "File not found or cannot be read: #{real_path}"
    end
  end

end
```

Then you can use it in your CSS:

```
.icon {
  background-image: inline-svg-image('icons/icon.svg', '#555');
}
```

You will need to edit your SVG files and replace any fill attributes in the markup with fill="{color}"

The icon path is always relative to your images_dir parameter in the same config.rb file.

Similar to some of the other solutions, but this is pretty clean and keeps your SCSS files tidy!

Comment: this is from a [github-issue](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1460#issuecomment-65132746). Just referencing it here in case somebody wants to read the discussion there

Answer (score 3):

In some (very specific) situations this might be achieved by using a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter). For example, you can change a blue SVG image to purple by rotating the hue 45 degrees using `filter: hue-rotate(45deg);`. Browser support is minimal but it's still an interesting technique.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/g7tnbxvz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

for monochrome background you could use a svg with a mask, where the background color should be displayed

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
    <defs>
        <mask id="Mask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <polyline stroke-width="2.5" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="square" fill="none" transform="translate(10.373882, 8.762969) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-10.373882, -8.762969) " points="7.99893906 13.9878427 12.7488243 13.9878427 12.7488243 3.53809523"></polyline>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="white" mask="url(#Mask)" />
</svg>
```

and than use this css

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
background-image: url(your/path/to.svg);
background-color: var(--color);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using a gradient and a monochrome icon as background and background-blend-mode to colorize the icon.
It requires the background-color to be white, else the whole background gets colored. I only tested on Chrome.

```css
.colored-background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, green, green), url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-color: #fff;
  background-blend-mode: lighten, normal;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center right .8em;
  background-size: auto, 0.6em;
  color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  height: 1.6em;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="colored-background">green icon from black svg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the show here, BUT, I was able to add a fill color to the SVG polygon, if you're able to directly edit the SVG code, so for example the following svg renders red, instead of default black.  I have not tested outside of Chrome though:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon 


        fill="red"


        fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" points="452.5,233.85 452.5,264.55 110.15,264.2 250.05,390.3 229.3,413.35 
47.5,250.7 229.3,86.7 250.05,109.75 112.5,233.5 "/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found for this, and to be cross browser (aka bulletproof), is to render the SVG with PHP and pass Query String to set the color.

The SVG, here called "arrow.php"

```
<?php
$fill = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fill');
$fill = strtolower($fill);
$fill = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/", '', $fill);
if(empty($fill)) $fill = "000000";
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="7.4" height="12" viewBox="0 0 7.4 12">
    <g>
        <path d="M8.6,7.4,10,6l6,6-6,6L8.6,16.6,13.2,12Z" transform="translate(-8.6 -6)" fill="#<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fill); ?>" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Then you call the image like this

```
.cssclass{ background-image: url(arrow.php?fill=112233); }
```

Works only with PHP. And remember that everytime you change the color value, your browser will load a new image.

Answer (score 0):

In **inlined** SVG, you may use

```
<path fill="currentColor" ....
```

and set font-color via [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword) in CSS.

Works for monochrome icons only because you can only set the current text-color with this css prop.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Adel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901574/adel)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904983/959484):

When you already have a background image and you want to colorize it (e.g. with green) like when styling an AG Grid Material theme with a custom icon, you should use:

```css
.ag-theme-material {
    --ag-icon-image-asc: url('arrow-up.svg');
    --ag-icon-font-color-asc: transparent;
}

.ag-icon-asc::after {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-mask: var(--ag-icon-image-asc) no-repeat center/cover;
    mask: var(--ag-icon-image-asc) no-repeat center/cover;
}
```

Note the reuse of the variables and the usage of `center/cover` for size changes being taken into account.

Answer (score -1):

**scss create function**

```
@function url-svg($icon) {
  @return url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,#{str-replace($icon, "#", "%23")}");
}
```

**scss use**

```
url-svg('<svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.125 0H1.875C0.84082 0 0 0.84082 0 1.875V10.3125C0 11.3467 0.84082 12.1875 1.875 12.1875H4.6875V14.6484C4.6875 14.9355 5.01563 15.1025 5.24707 14.9326L8.90625 12.1875H13.125C14.1592 12.1875 15 11.3467 15 10.3125V1.875C15 0.84082 14.1592 0 13.125 0Z" fill="#8A8A8F"/></svg>')
```

**css** generated

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.125 0H1.875C0.84082 0 0 0.84082 0 1.875V10.3125C0 11.3467 0.84082 12.1875 1.875 12.1875H4.6875V14.6484C4.6875 14.9355 5.01563 15.1025 5.24707 14.9326L8.90625 12.1875H13.125C14.1592 12.1875 15 11.3467 15 10.3125V1.875C15 0.84082 14.1592 0 13.125 0Z" fill="%238A8A8F"/></svg>')
```

> The **str-replace** function is used from **bootstrap**.

Answer (score -1):

Related to a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686882/change-img-src-svg-on-hover-in-css) that is linked to here, but not related directly to this question.

So in case, anyone needs actually to replace `src` like in the linked question, there is already an answer there. Furthermore if anyone is coming from Vue, and the `src` path is change on compile, I've come up with a different solution.

In my case, the parent element is a link, but it could be anything really.

```html
<a
  v-for="document in documents" :key="document.uuid"
  :href="document.url"
  target="_blank"
  class="item flex align-items-center gap-2 hover-parent"
>
  <img alt="documents" class="icon" src="../assets/PDF.svg" />
  <strong>{{ document.name }}</strong>
  <img class="itemImage ml-auto hide-on-parent-hover" src="../assets/download-circular-button.svg" />
  <img class="itemImage ml-auto show-on-parent-hover" src="../assets/download-circular-button-hover.svg" />
</a>
```

```css
.hover-parent       .show-on-parent-hover { display: none }
.hover-parent       .hide-on-parent-hover { display: block }
.hover-parent:hover .show-on-parent-hover { display: block }
.hover-parent:hover .hide-on-parent-hover { display: none }
```

So the solution here is not to change `src` attribute, but instead to put both `<img>` elements in the DOM and only display the one that is needed.

If you don't have a parent element that's supposed to be hovered on, you can simply wrap both images in a `div`.

```html
<div class="hover-parent" >
  <img class="hide-on-parent-hover" src="../assets/download-circular-button.svg" />
  <img class="show-on-parent-hover" src="../assets/download-circular-button-hover.svg" />
</div>
```

You might also change CSS to the following, so the `.hover-parent` ancestor must be a direct parent:

```css
.hover-parent       > .show-on-parent-hover { display: none }
.hover-parent       > .hide-on-parent-hover { display: block }
.hover-parent:hover > .show-on-parent-hover { display: block }
.hover-parent:hover > .hide-on-parent-hover { display: none }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my favorite method, but your browser support must be very progressive. With the mask property you create a mask that is applied to an element. Everywhere the mask is opaque, or solid, the underlying image shows through. Where it’s transparent, the underlying image is masked out, or hidden. The syntax for a CSS mask-image is similar to background-image.[look at the codepen](http://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/wzsyC)`mask`

Answer (score -5):

A lot of IFs, but if your pre base64 encoded SVG starts:

```
<svg fill="#000000
```

Then the base64 encoded string will start:

```
PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSIjMDAwMDAw
```

if the pre-encoded string starts:

```
<svg fill="#bfa76e
```

then this encodes to:

```
PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSIjYmZhNzZl
```

Both encoded strings start the same:

```
PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSIj
```

The quirk of base64 encoding is every 3 input characters become 4 output characters. With the SVG starting like this then the 6-character hex fill color starts exactly on an encoding block 'boundary'.
Therefore you can easily do a cross-browser JS replace:

```
output = input.replace(/MDAwMDAw/, "YmZhNzZl");
```

But tnt-rox answer above is the way to go moving forward.

Comment: It seems public disliked the base64 use

Comment: This is ridiculous to write by hand but a great small lib idea. Bascially, base64 encode just parts of svg, swap as needed. (In my solution, I'm doing same but via components, pretty much free when prerendering vue, so no need for base64 here)

Comment: @revelt - this was written in 2016, SVG data-uris HAD to be base 64 encoded. Lot's has changed thankfully