# Modifying the colour of SVG sprite with background data

Tags: css, svg, sass, gulp

I'm trying to create a flexible sprite solution for my website whereby I can have one version of each icon within the sprite image but have the ability to change it';s colour dynamically. I know you can do this if you embed the SVG into your page but I don't want to do this as I will be using it as a background-image in css/sass. I have looked at the following article which looks promising and have it working as described in Chrome but having also looked at caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/#search=URI) I have also realised that IE only support base64 image data. This prevents me from changing the fill colours of the paths in my SVG data.

[Modify SVG fill color when being served as Background-Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image)

I am using gulp with my project and my question is, would I be able to convert something like this which will be in my sass file:

```
background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg> ... </svg>');
```

into a base64 version like so with gulp?

```
background:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uP...');
```

This would enable me to change the colours dynamically with variables etc in my sass but also have IE support.

This looked like it might be a possibility but I'm not sure if it would work as my image is data to begin with whereas in the example, it's an iamge URL.

http://stefanimhoff.de/2014/gulp-tutorial-7-base64/

Comment: What are you asking here?  Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-str2base64.

This allows me to wrap my SVG data string in the str2base64 function which then converts it. I run this task after my sass task to ensure the variables have been applied before the data is encoded.