# How to set a fill colour of an background/inline SVG?

Tags: css, svg

```css
.icon {
  width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" /></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class='icon'></div>
```

How do I set the fill colour (using CSS) of an inline/background SVG?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
You can't. It has to be in <svg> format

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon {
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
 -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" /></svg>');
   mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" /></svg>');
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33435726/368691 for a similar~ solution.