# How can change svg fill color by css?

Tags: html, css, svg

In html

```
<img src="../../Images/newsletter_icons/{{tool.Tool}}.svg" />
```

In css

```
svg.icon{
        fill:red
       }
```

*Note: I have  added class name 'icon' manually in my all svg tag.

Comment: You can't. Images are self-contained. You'd have to put the CSS in the svg file itself.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image

Comment: Could you please see this ... add an extralegal link to svg file but it is not working. here it is https://jsfiddle.net/Shishir/rczesgop/

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90705408/basic-theme-color.css" >` but it still won't work as an image as images must be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to the image to recolor it and call the filter through CSS.