# The css Style Sheets work only when I use External CSS but not inteneral with <style>

Tags: css, performance, stylesheet

I have attached the [link](https://easyupload.io/fybjz2) to the site files(zip), I just want to attach the css to the html so that I will not have a call for a file that wastes my time and slows the site down. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken css style syntax at this line( #370)

`input[type='checkbox']:checked{
 ....
  background-image: url(...)
}`

Here i see a nested style tag which is causing the problem, where an svg file using as background contains a style tag.

Comment: I went over the code and it looks good, can you please correct the code by your method and send it to me?

Comment: As per my knowledge, when you use with in the file like that, it becomes nested <style> declaration with in a declaration.. so the css processor is not able to parse the css correctly ( identifying the corresponding closing tag), 
here is an example of your problem
`<style>
  h1{
   font-size: 20px;
    <style>
   h1{
   color: green;
   }
  </style>
  }
</style>`

but this nesting is not a problem outside  declaration block, where it can identify nesting  ( in the above case its not) 

When you use it as external file, you dont have outer style

Comment: So there no eazy way to fix it ?

Comment: you need to rewrite that declaration a bit, 
see if you can just remove  this from the source and if that has no impact `<style type="text/css">.st0{fill:#fff;}</style>` or you need to rewrite that declaration like the answers here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/modify-svg-fill-color-when-being-served-as-background-image

Comment: I try but it makes problem on site.

Comment: Its working for me without the inner <style> whats the problem you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

All error is in the code:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml .................
```

There are three of them, remove them from your code then it will work.

Download the `index.html` file code: https://send.firefox.com/download/db2db4d53aa9f186/#yK1lwyKPBiwOrPwt73fzwQ

Comment: When I use your code the site does not work well on mobile. The amburger menu not work properly.

Comment: You have no script file to target Hamberger menu. To add icons don't use CSS, it will be easy and less code to add icon through HTML. Are you a beginner. I can help if you want.