# Change img src SVG on hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

html:

`<img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">`

css:

```
.logo-img path:hover {fill: red;}
```

Is there a way to change a the hex code on a img svg on hover?

Comment: I ran into same kind of problem earlier. What I did was to use the image as a background of a division with width & height an then change the `background-image` property on hover. I wasn't able to change the source though.

Comment: @Martin I've tried to change it within the SVG file but no luck. Besides that I only tried to change fill to red as you can see. I couldnt find any other solution for in on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using CSS only, but you could do it with a bit of JavaScript, if you can change the HTML.

Something like:

```
onmouseover="this.src='newSrcHover.jpg';"
```

Or you can change the `background-image: url('linkToNewImage')`property on `:hover`... while that does change an image on hover and may be sufficient for some, it's not src. The JS one is.

Answer (score 2):

An svg in a src attribute is loaded as a file, so it won't be editable.

If you intend to modify **fill**, **stroke** and so on, you should use your `logo.svg` in an `<svg>` tag instead of an `<img />`.