# Add color to svg background icon

Tags: css

Hi  is there a way to change color of svg image of background like this

```css
  .icon {
    background: url("~images/icon.svg") center no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<i class="icon"></i>
```

For example I need it icon to fill with blue color, but it is not possible, with background like this, is there any way?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/how-to-modify-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-image-when-being-served-as-background-ima)

Answer (score 1):

If you load your SVG in the HTML as an Element instead of a Background Image CSS Attribute you can change the fill property of that Element

```css
#mySVG
{
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#000" viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="mySVG">
  <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it as background

Answer (score 0):

If the SVG has a transparent background, you can set `background-image` to the SVG and `background-color` as you see fit. They will stack.