# Is CSS Sprite compatible to SVG

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I've tried using svg on my background. However when I'm
using an SVG file it's not working fine all Icons is showing and it's
too small. My goal is like on the png file type by using
background-position I can control the position of the image that I
converted to CSS Sprite. Can anyone tell me how to do it using svg
file? Also I'm asking if it's possible to change the fill color of the
svg icon that I converted into CSS Sprite?

Also please see image below when I'm trying to use the svg file. All
icons are showing and it's super small. Are CSS Sprite and SVG compatible?

```css
.icon-one ._icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background: url(../media/icons/toolbar/toolbar-icon-svg-type-01.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-one">
  <div class="_ico">
</div>

<div class="icon-two">
  <div class="_ico">
</div>

<div class="icon-three">
  <div class="_ico">
</div>
```

[image: SVG Icons]

[image]

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant CSS

Comment: hi @mplungjan. even I updated the CSS it's not working also cause the background is not existing in this file

Comment: using png is working fine by the way. However, when using SVG file it's not working at all my icons is showing in super small size like a dotted. Also, question by using a SVG file can I also control the fill color of the SVG inside that file?

Comment: I think you can use background-size Css property regardless of png or SVG graphics. Also you can set the background color off SVGs by Css as: .icon {
  fill: black;
}

Comment: hi, ihpar thanks it's working using background size. Also 1 question by using an SVG file can I also control the fill color of the icons?

Comment: Youre adding styles to the class `_icon` but youre using the class `_ico` in your HTML.

Comment: You can't change the fill property of a svg background image. Common workarounds:  1. colorize your element by a filter. like `filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(-70deg) saturate(5);` 2. use the similar `mask-image` property: you're actually setting a background-color and mask it by your svg shape (won't work for input elements) ... and many more. See also these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/how-to-modify-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-image-when-being-served-as-background-ima#answer-46904983)