# Using CSS Variables in SVG as background image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG Image which is to be loaded on my webpage as the background. Hence the css for it is:

```css
body{
    background: url('path/to/the/svg/image.svg')
    .
    .
}
```

I have a css variable named `accent-primary-color`, which defines the accent color of the page (and is set by the user) and I want the color to be reflected in the SVG as the main color. The svg file has a style tag as follows:

```
<style>
    .outline-paths{
        fill: var(--accent-primary-color);
    }
</style>
```

I would have achieved the color in SVG, if it were a code in the HTML file, but in case of `background-image`, that won't work because its and external SVG, being used as background and it doesn't have access to the CSS Variables.

I also found methods to achieve the thing using `Data URI` methods like:

```css
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>');
```

but I can't use that because the SVG Code is very long (602 Lines without minifying), and it also has several single and double quotes in the file.

Is there any other method through which the SVG File can access the CSS Variables while being used as a background image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify the fill color of an SVG image when being served as background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/how-to-modify-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-image-when-being-served-as-background-ima)

Comment: @the.marolie I already saw the solution, and unfortunately, as I described in the question, I cannot use the method suggested in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a modern Web Component

- Load the SVG from an external location
- encode characters **"** and **%**
- read CSS Property `--rectcolor`
- inject it as `<style>` into the SVG
- inject as `backgroundImage`

```html
<style>
 :root{
  --rectcolor:rebeccapurple;
  }
</style>
<svg-import-background src="//svg-cdn.github.io/red.svg"></svg-import-background>
<svg-import-background src="//svg-cdn.github.io/blue.svg"></svg-import-background>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-import-background", class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
      let svg = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text();
      svg = svg.replace(/\>[\t\s\n ]+\</g, "><"); // replace all BETWEEN tags
      svg = svg.replace(/#/g, "%23");
      svg = svg.replace(/"/g, "'");
      let color = getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue("--rectcolor");
      let style = `<style>rect{fill:${color}}</style>`;
      svg = svg.replace("</svg>",style + `</svg>`);
      this.style.display="inline-block";
      this.style.width="100px";
      this.style.height="100px";
      this.style.backgroundImage = `url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,${svg}")`;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing work out there! I tried the idea you suggested, but I can't display the svg on the background. But, I know the method is correct, because the console displays the svg very well. To get the desired output, I would need a bit more clarification on, where is `this` referencing to. Can you please let me know. Also, it would be helpful if you provide me a reference to documentation on the method. Thanks!

Comment: ``this`` is the DOM element ``<svg-import-background>`` you can use any DOM element