# Changing fill and/or stroke color of loaded svg using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

In the following example, I'm creating my own list item icons by embedding them as background images to the list item elements and setting `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`.

```css
ul
{
padding: 0;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-home'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 20px;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='blue' class='bi bi-linkedin' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

For one HTML document, I'm OK with having these list markers remain blue as shown above. However, for another document, I'd like to default to another color, for example red.

Applying a filter will not do, because it seems to also affect the text content of the list items. I just need to modify the color of the list item marker.

How can I enforce this behavior using CSS? I.e. how can I get the list markers to look blue in one page and red in another page without duplicating the entire data link in `url()`?

The mentioned duplicate is not a duplicate because it doesn't address the corner case of loading an SVG using the `background-image` property. When an SVG is used as a background image, it's not part of the DOM and therefore can't be directly manipulated with JavaScript

Comment: But those **are** the solutions that exist. There aren't any others.

Comment: That duplicate question doesn't tell me whether I can or cannot implement any of the provided solutions (even if they are the only ones that exist) to a background-image loaded in the way I have described.

Comment: One of the links discusses background-image specifically. In the end you can always use multiple distinct urls with different colours.

Comment: If all the icons/SVGs are mono color you can let the background-image/SVG mask off a background-color defined in CSS. So, either use the background-image or the mask CSS property.

Comment: Almost all _duplicate_ answers **post-process** DOM. With modern native Web Components you can **pre-process** and generate DOM with ``background-image`` dynamically; kinda like done in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608466/using-css-variables-in-svg-as-background-image/75613015#75613015

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify the fill color of an SVG image when being served as background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367868/how-to-modify-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-image-when-being-served-as-background-ima)

Answer (score 0):

As [@chrwahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322084/chrwahl) mentioned, you can use [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) instead of [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

See example below of your initial approach, but using `mask-image` CSS instead of `background-image` CSS for your svg image `url()`...

```css
:root {
  --DodgerBlue: #1E90FF;
  --MediumSlateBlue: #7B68EE;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li a {
  color: var(--DodgerBlue);
  text-decoration: none;
}

li::before {
  background: var(--DodgerBlue);
  content: '';
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li:hover a {
  color: var(--MediumSlateBlue);
}

li:hover::before {
  background: var(--MediumSlateBlue);
}

li:nth-child(1)::before {
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

li:nth-child(2)::before {
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='black' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='black' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-size: 20px;
  -webkit-mask-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
</ul>
```

See fiddle version... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/Ljgofkt5/34/

---

Here is another example using same `mask-image` method, but a more manageable syntax using `i` html tags for your icons, which can be resized easily by adjusting the font size of the parent tags...

```css
:root {
  --DodgerBlue: #1E90FF;
  --MediumSlateBlue: #7B68EE;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.first-list {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.second-list {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.third-list {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li a {
  color: var(--DodgerBlue);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.25em;
}

.icon::before {
  background: var(--DodgerBlue);
  content: '&nbsp;';
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: auto 100%;
  -webkit-mask-size: auto 100%;
  mask-position: center;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
}

li:hover a {
  color: var(--MediumSlateBlue);
}

li:hover a .icon::before {
  background: var(--MediumSlateBlue);
}

.icon-home::before {
  --IconHome: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3Cpath d='M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpolyline points='9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: var(--IconHome);
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--IconHome);
}

.icon-linkedin::before {
  --IconLinkedin: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='black' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1.146C0 .513.526 0 1.175 0h13.65C15.474 0 16 .513 16 1.146v13.708c0 .633-.526 1.146-1.175 1.146H1.175C.526 16 0 15.487 0 14.854V1.146zm4.943 12.248V6.169H2.542v7.225h2.401m-1.2-8.212c.837 0 1.358-.554 1.358-1.248-.015-.709-.52-1.248-1.342-1.248-.822 0-1.359.54-1.359 1.248 0 .694.521 1.248 1.327 1.248h.016zm4.908 8.212V9.359c0-.216.016-.432.08-.586.173-.431.568-.878 1.232-.878.869 0 1.216.662 1.216 1.634v3.865h2.401V9.25c0-2.22-1.184-3.252-2.764-3.252-1.274 0-1.845.7-2.165 1.193v.025h-.016a5.54 5.54 0 0 1 .016-.025V6.169h-2.4c.03.678 0 7.225 0 7.225h2.4' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: var(--IconLinkedin);
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--IconLinkedin);
}
```

```html
<ul class="first-list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i> Second item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i> Second item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="third-list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i> Second item</a></li>
</ul>
```

See fiddle version... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/cunrsj2v/43/