# inline svg filter in css

Tags: css, svg

After reading this question: [Inline SVG in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css) (works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome)

```
body { background-image: 
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>........</svg>");
      }
```

I tried to apply some filter effects with

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>........</svg>#filter01")
```

It worked on FF, but didn't work on Chrome.

What's the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you need to apply a filter to the svg? Just define and use the filter inside the svg instead, that will work in most browsers.

Comment: @Erik Dahlström I know it's better to embed an inline SVG element or use an external .svg file. But I just want to know if CSS can do something like that.

Comment: try https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Answer (score 1):

try to use escape on the data string ,
like

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%3E........%3C/svg%3E#filter01")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can fix it. This was only ever fully supported by Firefox and this usage will now be superseded by the *-filter property.