# Can jQuery inject svg data into css background-image:url()?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I'm wondering if there's a way in jQuery to grab some SVG data included in a div on a page and place that data into a CSS `background-image` url?  I'm trying to do this instead of loading an external SVG file, as I'd like to have a completely self-contained HTML file.  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var svgData = $("#div-containing-svg").html()
$("other-div").css({backgroundImage:svgData});
```

Is this possible? And further, would it work across browsers?

Comment: I've seen this done as a canvas - how flexible are you?

Comment: It can be done as a data URI, e.g. `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxu [and so on]");` so if you can massage your data into that form, somehow...? I found http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/SJjJb/ which uses straight SVG but it only appears to be webkit-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
var image = $('#svg-container').html();
$('#elem').css('background-image', 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + image);
```

Is it cross-browser? Here you can see a compatibility matrix: http://caniuse.com/svg-css

- The SVG content should be url escaped

Answer (score 0):

A working example of the answer by @minko-geschev:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626701/960592

The provided answer uses base64 encoding, instead of escaping.