# SVG fill in CSS?

Tags: css, svg, fill

I'm trying to change the SVG fill color to white, then on :hover change it to a different color, i've tried fill:; with no luck.

```
header nav ul li a.settings{ 
  background-color: #5bd999;
  background-image: url("../img/entypo/cog.svg");
  fill:white;
}

header nav ul li a.settings:hover{ 
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Not sure that would work with a remote svg image. I think it would have to be inline, or have the css included as part of the svg file.

Comment: You can't change `fill` using CSS when your SVG is in an external file.

Comment: Can I embed the SVG code in CSS rather than in HTML?

Comment: @user3574766: Yes, you could do that. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css