# Dynamically resize inline SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG that is being rendered inline `<div className="app-details__icon-large" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svg }} />`. It needs to be rendered as such (not in `img` tag, or background) so that I can style certain properties within the svg. While I'm successfully styling (using css selectors) properties that are not set in the svg, I cannot set the height and width because it's being override by the inline height/width properties. So what is the best way, given an svg with a height/width, so control the height and width from CSS? Is it possible? Or if not, what is best practice for resizing inline svgs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline SVG in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css)

Comment: it may be a case of using the ever-hated `!important` tag, unless you can override the inline styling for these using specificity

Comment: The SVG will have width and height set inline on the svg tag, remove those then plain CSS will allow you to adjust the width and height properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you inline SVGs you don't need Javascript. For example, you can scale to 48px a 24px icon like this:

```html
<div class="Icon">
  <svg class="Icon-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">...</svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.Icon {
  width: 48px;
}
.Icon svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I've looked around so much for a solution for this and yours was the only one that has worked so far on inline SVG. Thank you.

Comment: So much extra noise on the internet regarding SVGs. This is pretty much all I needed.