# Using svg in IE11

Tags: css, firefox, svg, internet-explorer-11

I find that this svg renders correctly in Chrome, Firefox and IE11:

```
background:#000 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42px" height="42px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><circle cx="21px" cy="21px" r="21" fill="black"/><rect x="9px" y="10px" width="25px" height="22px" fill="white"/></g></svg>');
```

However, I am having trouble having these svg icons working across browsers:

This works on Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11:

```
background:#000 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42px" height="42px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><g><circle cx="21px" cy="21px" r="21px" fill="black"/><g><polyline points="20 30 15 20 25 15 20 7" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/><circle cx="20" cy="30" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/><circle cx="20" cy="7" r="2.2" fill="white" stroke="white"/></g></g></svg>');
}
```

I find that this svg works in Chrome only:

```
background:#000 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42" height="42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><circle r="21" id="svg_2" cy="21" cx="21" fill="#050404"/><path id="svg_3" d="m52.86,21.00981l6.42885,-13.71338l17.14235,0l6.42882,13.71338l-6.42882,13.71425l-17.14235,0l-6.42885,-13.71425z" fill="#ffffff"/></g></svg>');
}
```

Is there some way to get these svgs working cross browser. I used these svgs based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css)

I have tried the following combinations:

```
background:black url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42px" height="42px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><circle cx="21px" cy="21px" r="21" fill="black"/><rect x="9px" y="10px" width="25px" height="22px" fill="white"/></g></svg>'),linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);

background:%23000 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42px" height="42px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><circle cx="21px" cy="21px" r="21" fill="black"/><rect x="9px" y="10px" width="25px" height="22px" fill="white"/></g></svg>'),linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
```

I also tried using the fallback suggested here but it always renders the png:

```
body {
  background: url(fallback.png);
  background: url(background.svg),
    linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking console?

Comment: @Justinas I did, is there any message that appears regarding the css? I did not find any.

Comment: I'm seeing some different behavior. The 1st one doesn't seem to work on my IE11 (Win7), and the 3rd just shows black for me even in Chrome (I just applied the CSS to the body of a fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just write out any old set of characters and have them be a url. Some characters have special meanings.

The character # is supposed to be reserved as the start of a fragment identifier. Chrome does not implement this correctly though but Firefox and IE do which is why the final example does not work.

If you replace all the # characters by %23 in the final url it will work in Firefox and IE. E.g.

```css
body {
  background:#000 url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="42" height="42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><circle r="21" id="svg_2" cy="21" cx="21" fill="%23050404"/><path id="svg_3" d="m5.86,21.00981l6.42885,-13.71338l17.14235,0l6.42882,13.71338l-6.42882,13.71425l-17.14235,0l-6.42885,-13.71425z" fill="%23ffffff"/></g></svg>');
}
```

I'm not sure about the middle URL, it seems fine to me. base64 encoding it may make it work in IE.

Comment: an example would be helpful, I have tried using %23 instead of # but I get the same error.

Comment: I've added an example which works in Firefox. It just changes the # characters as I suggested.

Comment: Not working with IE11 though, I am using [this](http://hastebin.com/muzobezowa.xml) as the `background` with `.` replaced with `%2E`

Comment: You'll have to experiment removing things till you find out what's wrong then. Change the non-working version one element/attribute at a time till you figure it out.