# How change path and polyline in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, jointjs

I have two icons in svg.

**Updated:**

1. [one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gxvqdx)
2. [two](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gexMjz)

First of all, is it possible to make this icons using same markup?
For example:

`<g>
  <circle ... />
  <path ... />
</g>`?

Because i can operate only with classes. That mean that i want to change their styles in `css` and that why i want same markup for both icons.

Also i want remove `cx="9" cy="9"` from both icons, because this icon is part of the `<rect />` and should be placed  strictly on the verge of this `<rect />`. And this `cx` and `cy` move it sideways. If i just remove them, then icon become broken a bit. I need to change attributes of `path` and `polyline` also. How i can do it? Thank you

Comment: The two links point to identical markup. What is your point?

Comment: @ccprog that's the bad thing of including external links .. he's edting the code ... maybe because he got some answer and now all his answer is irrelevant to new comer.

Comment: Sorry, i updated links

Answer (score 1):

As for your re-use of SVG that part already has an answer here:
[Inline SVG in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10768451/125981)

You can do a lot with this using just CSS for example:

```css
.firstxxx,
.secondxxx {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -1.1em;
  left: 6em;
}
.secondxxx circle{fill:blue;}

.containerthing {
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerthing">1. One
  <svg class="firstxxx" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="311.7px" height="311.5px" viewBox="0 0 311.7 311.5" enable-background="new 0 0 311.7 311.5"
    xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g>
      <circle magnet="true" fill="#E88585" cx="9" cy="9" r="9"></circle>
      <g transform="translate(5.625000, 5.625000)" stroke="#F8F9FC">
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062" transform="translate(3.444609, 3.175632) scale(-1, 1) translate(-3.444609, -3.175632) "></path>
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="containerthing">2. Two
  <svg class="secondxxx" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="311.7px" height="311.5px" viewBox="0 0 311.7 311.5" enable-background="new 0 0 311.7 311.5"
    xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g>
      <circle magnet="true" fill="#E88585" cx="9" cy="9" r="9"></circle>
      <g transform="translate(5.625000, 5.625000)" stroke="#F8F9FC">
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062" transform="translate(3.444609, 3.175632) scale(-1, 1) translate(-3.444609, -3.175632) "></path>
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if you want to remove `cx="9" cy="9"`, you can use `transform: translate()`

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<svg version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
  x="0px" y="0px" width="311.7px" height="311.5px" viewBox="0 0 311.7 311.5" enable-background="new 0 0 311.7 311.5"
  xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g>
      <circle magnet="true" fill="#E88585" r="9" transform="translate(9, 9)"></circle>
      <g transform="translate(5.625000, 5.625000)" stroke="#F8F9FC">
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062" transform="translate(3.444609, 3.175632) scale(-1, 1) translate(-3.444609, -3.175632) "></path>
        <path d="M0.548779871,6.31256521 L6.34043825,0.0386997062"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I want to remove it because this icon is part of the `<rect />` and should be placed  strictly on the verge of this `<rect />`. And this `cx` and `cy` move it sideways

Answer (score 0):

You can position the shape where you want and reference the SVG through `xlink:href` in the shape's attributes definition along with a specific markup through the [JointJS Devs plugin](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#shapes.devs). E.g.:

```
joint.shapes.devs.Model.define('app.MyWindow', {
    markup: `<image/><text/>`,
    position: {
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    },
    size: {
      width: 10,
      height: 10
    },
    attrs: {
      image: {
        width: 8,
        height: 8,
        'xlink:href': 'assets/my_svg.svg'
      },
    }
});
```