# SVG file not getting shown in HTML

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

I am trying to display a locale SVG file but it keeps showing the alt attribute of the element.

[image]

The img tag does have data in the src

[image]

this is my import `import  appleMusic from '../public/Applemusic.svg'`

next.config.js

```
module.exports =
    withImages(
        withTM(
            withFonts(
                {
                    enableSvg: true,
                    webpack(config, options) {
                        return config;
                    },
                })

        )
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Your data is base64 encoded; what is the data when it is unencoded? Typically SVG should not be base64 encoded, but really the SVG can be put straight into your HTML. There are lots of examples online for how to do this

Comment: There will be some useful pointers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css)

Comment: perhaps the encoded image data doesn't decode to a valid image.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the SVG's path in the `img`'s source, e.g., `<img src="/Applemusic.svg" />`?

Comment: @juliomalves that worked, only if I use '/Applemusic.svg' and not the relative path to the public folder for some weird reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the SVG's path directly in the `img`'s source.

```js
<img src="/Applemusic.svg" />
```

Files inside the `public/` folder can be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

Comment: Like I commented on @juliomalves's answer, this works very well